# Building a new ImageCollection based on the calculated result

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to build the ImageCollection based on the result after mosaic in the same day. Although I try the function `ee.ImageCollection.combine()`, but I find that the new ImageCollection is that the image at everyday become every band in the same Image. I want the image at same day was in the one Image, and the different day of image in different Image. How can I work?

```
coefficientsSentinel = ee.Array([
    [0.215942694,0.138081051,-0.013683431,-0.023024016,-0.000836141,0.00309505,0.002762451,-0.000402219,-0.082173981,-0.082374823],
    [-0.028842179,-0.039586092,-0.107684568,-0.049530622,0.101244397,0.143161928,0.150045189,0.153501264,-0.098781754,-0.182308042],
    [-0.105684597,-0.023685974,0.198952293,0.146140045,-0.025807867,-0.068956692,-0.077812648,-0.07958239,0.355654868,0.466680097],
    [-0.112591178,0.010607211,0.144167147,0.129118215,0.025853564,-0.005544775,-0.007429916,-0.005900238,-0.059040443,-0.111123577]
  ]);

def clip(image):
    image = image.clip(area1)
    return image

def maskS2clouds(image):
    qa = image.select('QA60');
    cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
    cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0) \
      .And(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
    return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);

def UNVI(image):
    image1 = image.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4','B5','B6', 'B7','B8', 'B8A','B11', 'B12']);
    arrayImage1D = image1.toArray();
    arrayImage2D = arrayImage1D.toArray(1);
    componentsImage = ee.Image(coefficientsSentinel)\
        .matrixMultiply(arrayImage2D)\
        .arrayProject([0])\
        .arrayFlatten([['Cw', 'Cv', 'Cs', 'C4']]);
    Cw = componentsImage.select("Cw");
    Cv = componentsImage.select("Cv");
    Cs = componentsImage.select("Cs");
    C4 = componentsImage.select("C4");
    unvi1 =(Cv.subtract(Cs.divide(10)).subtract(C4)).divide(Cw.add(Cv).add(Cs)).rename('UNVI');
    return image.select().addBands(unvi1);
    
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterDate('2020-04-01',"2020-04-05")\
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',50))\
                  .map(maskS2clouds).map(UNVI).map(clip).filterBounds(area1);

# visParams = {
#   'min': -0.1,
#   'max': 3.0,
#   'palette': [
#     'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
#     '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
#     '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
#   ],
# };

Map.addLayer(dataset);

origion_datelist = dataset.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(),["system:index"]).get("list")
date = origion_datelist.getInfo()
print(date)
datelist = []
datelist.append(date[0][0:8])
for i in range(1,len(date)):
    if date[i][0:8] in datelist:
        continue
    else:
        datelist.append(date[i][0:8])
print(datelist)

def mosaic(dataset):
    col_mosaic = ee.ImageCollection(
        dataset.filter(ee.Filter.stringStartsWith('system:index', datelist[0][0:31])).qualityMosaic("UNVI")\
        .rename(datelist[0][0:31]).set("data",datelist[0][0:31])
    )
    for i in range(1, len(datelist)):
        add_mosaic = ee.ImageCollection(
            dataset.filter(ee.Filter.stringStartsWith('system:index', datelist[i][0:31])).qualityMosaic("UNVI")\
            .rename(datelist[i][0:31]).set("data",datelist[i][0:31]))
        col_mosaic = col_mosaic.combine(add_mosaic)
    return col_mosaic
                       
imagecol = mosaic(dataset)
print(imagecol.getInfo())

Map = geemap.Map()
Map
```